# ecommerce templates

Tags: php, e-commerce

I am currently working with a [eCommerce](http://www.ecommercetemplates.com/) site for a client but to keep things organized I am wanting to group some pages in sub folders. However, because of the nature of eCommerce it relies on several pages in its base folder (search.php, products.php, etc) to generate some of the pages of content and therefore I cannot really have any subfolders unless I make copies of all the necessary pages into each seperate subdirectory and then it makes everything more complicated not to mention creates issues of its own.

I hope my question is clear enough and I was wondering what options are in a situation such as this?

Is there a way I can setup a redirect page for each of these common pages inside the sub directory to redirect to the base files but maintain any POST data?

Comment: Sounds like a custom-built system? You really should look at MVC design and using a router to direct requests rather than having physical files in each folder / subfolder. Sorry, but I do think that's the best answer to solve the overall problem. There are also many great open source solutions for eCommerce systems..

Comment: Cheers!!, ASP.NET Open Source Complete eCommerce Solution "AspxCommerce 2.0" Get it Now from CodePlex: https://aspxcommerce.codeplex.com/downloads/get/680898
 
 For more detail visit: http://www.aspxcommerce.com/
 For Demo:
 Front End : http://demo.aspxcommerce.com/ 
 Back End  : http://demoadmin.aspxcommerce.com/
 
 New Features: http://www.aspxcommerce.com/What-is-New.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can try store the filtered post values to session(preferred),cache,Database, or just include a php script into to the script in which you post the form data.